# Firebase database permission denied when rules were changed

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

I'm unable to access the firebase database in react native app after updating the rules like this

```
{
  "rules": {
     "main_data":{
         "$uid": {
           "xx1":{
             ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
             ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
           },
             "xx2":{
             ".read": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
             ".write": "auth != null && auth.uid == $uid",
             }
        },
    },
  }
}
```

and I have the json structure like

```
main_data:{
    {"uid":{
       "xx1":{"id":"uid","d2":"val2","d3":"val3","d4":"d4","d5":"val5","d6":"val6"}
      },
       "xx2":"value"}
   }
```

And I got this error in react native app

```
@firebase/database: FIREBASE WARNING: update at /main_data/UID failed: permission_denied
```

I'm accessing it by the following code

```
firebase.database().ref('main_data').child(UID).child("xx1 or xx2")
            .on("value", data=>{
                console.log(data)
            })
```

**UPDATE**
: I forgot to share the write code

```
 firebase.database().ref('main_data/' + UID).update({
    xx2: "Some_value",
 }).then(() => {
    console.log("Success!!")
 }).catch((e) => {                                                                        
    console.log(e)
 })
```

Comment: The warning talks about an "update", while your code only shows how you're trying to read data.

Comment: I didn't understand that because in my cloud function permission denied received as output

Comment: Thanks for the updated code, but that's still not enough to help. We can't see how `UID` is initialized, the error messages makes it seems like that's a hard-coded string value, and we have no idea how you initialize your Cloud Functions. Please don't just give us snippet from your code. Instead reproduce the problem in isolation, and then give us the entire-but-minimal repo. Also see [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Its fine, now its solved it was issue of different firebase packages in my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it after wasting the time,,, actually it was the package mismatch issue that I was using in my project